# How did the neighborhood of Harlem vote in the 2016 presidential election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, new-york

I was thinking about the neighborhood of Harlem in New York City. I read that only 3 percent of the voters in this neighborhood are registered as Republicans and over 80% are registered as Democrats. So, I want to know about how the neighborhood voted in the 2016 presidential election. According to the different precincts that I randomly selected, it appears that Trump got ~2.5% of the vote there. Is that an accurate analysis?

Comment: Where I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlem#/map/0

Comment: Harlem is no longer homogeneous.

Comment: Try to follow that map. I'm not even going to ask what that thing about Harlem not being homogenous means. I have a feeling and I don't think that is relevant.

Comment: I know Harlem well enough without the map.

Comment: That was just to make sure. I thought you would but needed to make it clear.

Comment: Harlem is divided into South, Central and North Harlem with different voting patterns. So your 2.5% does not mean much. In general, New York has voted strongly Democratic for long time.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Now I understand what you mean by homogenous. I was thinking about those Harlems put together.

Comment: It appears that you already know the answer to this question, as you state the answer in your question.  Please feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 3):

This was actually quite tricky to collate. There is no official list that I could find of electoral precincts within Harlem, and I didn't want to do it manually, so I instead used [this shapefile](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Community-Districts/yfnk-k7r4) for New York's Community Districts. Manhattan Community Board 10 is roughly the correct boundaries for Harlem. I overlayed the district with [this shapefile](https://geodata.lib.berkeley.edu/catalog/nyu-2451-34548) for New York's precincts, which gave me the list I was after.

After that, it was just a matter of matching up the data with the [precinct electoral results](https://github.com/openelections/openelections-data-ny/blob/master/2016/20161108__ny__general__precinct.csv) courtesy of Open Elections. For a Trump vote, I counted any vote for the Republican or Conservative tickets; for a Clinton vote, any vote for the Democratic, Working Families, or Women's Equality tickets.

Using this definition, Harlem placed a total of 1,270 votes for Trump, and 47,965 for Clinton - equivalent to a two-party advantage of D+95. 1,102 votes were placed for other candidates, so Trump attained 2.52% of the overall vote in the neighborhood.  Below is a map showing the two-party advantage on a per-precinct basis.

The most Republican precinct in terms of percentage was 022/71, with 19 votes for Trump compared to 364 for Clinton, a two-party advantage of D+90, while the most Democratic precinct was 020/71, with just 6 votes for Trump compared to 741 for Clinton, a two-party advantage of D+98.

[image]